# Would like to install Entity Framework 5 with VS2012 but I'm lost

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I installed Visual Studio 2012 and migrated a project from Visual Studio 2010 with Entity Framework 4.3 and .Net Framework 4.0

Now I would like to reference Entity Framework 5.0 and .Net 4.5

BUT when I go to the Manage Nuget Package window and search for EntityFramework. It says that Entity Framework 5 is already installed (there is no 'Install' button and I have a green check). This is strange because when I take a look in my explorer window for this project and get the properties of the reference 'EntityFramework' I see that this is the version 4.4.0.0. I agree that the path is told to be 5.0 but what? I don't understand anymore which version is installed.

[image]

Any help please?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove EntityFramework package from your project, switch project to .NET 4.5 and add the package again. EF 4.4 and 5.0 represent "the same package" but the difference is the version of .NET they are targeting.